# Kendo Grid - Using Different Icon in same Column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI to render data in grid format. In grid there is a column of status which can have values like completed, error, in progress etc. Now to make it more convenient I want to represent it using images. In case of single icon I can use below code in COLUMNS array:

```
columns:[
{
    field: "oper",
    title: "Operation"      
},
{
    field: "exedate",
    title: "Date"
},
{
    field: "status",
    title: "Status",
    template: '<img src="/resources/icons/user_green.png"/>
}]
```

But now, how to represent multiple icons and that to with condition based on status value that I am not able to find out?

Comment: Thanks in advance, if somebody can share any link or available demo if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can have control over the template if you pass a function.

```
{
   field: "status",
   title: "Status",
   template: function(dataRow){

         var icon = 'red.png'

         switch(dataRow.status){
             // Assign here the icon as you please.
         }

         return '<img src="/resources/icons/' + icon + '"/>';
   }
}
```

Another solution is to define CSS classes to the different statuses.

```
.statusicon.good
{
   background: url('green.png')
}

.statusicon.bad
{
   background: url('red.png')
}
```

And then just render the css class in your template.

```
{
    field: "status",
    title: "Status",
    template: '<div class="statusicon #: status #"></div>
}
```

Comment: how can I capture onClick event when user click on that icon. Also I need to call a JS function and pass data from dataRow so how that can  be done? Current Implementation is : attributes:{onclick:"onClickEvent(event);"}

Comment: Don't do it like this... use jQuery event delegation. If your grid container is called #grid, you can declare a single click handler, like this:  $('#grid').on('click', '.statusicon', function(domElement){   })